# Accent codes in XML ANSI

Tags: xml, cdata

I have an XML document, it has to be in ANSI and it have Spanish accents, I don't knoow how can I do it inside the CDATA tag:

```
<name>
    <![CDATA[Introducció]]>
</name>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, "ANSI" was a term introduced by Microsoft to describe their first attempts at doing 8-bit character sets, which didn't actually conform to any ANSI standard, and were a range of different character sets anyway. Thankfully, Microsoft no longer use the term, which was always a misnomer. You probably mean either iso-8859-1, or its Microsoft variant cp1252.

Secondly, whether a particular encoding is recognized has nothing to do with CDATA sections. If it works inside a CDATA section then it will work outside, and vice versa.

The key thing is to make sure that the character encoding you use in the file is named in the XML declaration at the start of the file, for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```